Cancel the execution inside a method by new call of the method
We do have a method that is called by various execution points, like events, commands etc. These entry points can follow each other very quickly under certain circumstances. (i.e. when the user walk thru a list)
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();

void DoSomething()
{

    Task.Run(async() => {await longerrunningtask(cancellationTokenSource.Token)}, ...)
       .ContinueWith((t) => { .... });

}

How can we reach that when a new calls of DoSomething are comming in the last call execution of the Task is cancelled and the new one is starting multipletime?
DoSomething(); // execution starting but cancelled by the next call
DoSomething(); // execution starting but cancelled by the next call
DoSomething(); // execution starting and finished 


Take a look at the CancelableExecution class in this answer. It might be a solution to your problem.

Yes, you can just cancel the task cancellation source. This assumes DoSomething is only run on the UI thread.
async Task DoSomething()
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    var newCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationTokenSource = newCts;
    try{
        var result = await Task.Run(async() => {await longerrunningtask(newCts.Token)}, ...)
       // throw to enter the cancellation handler to ensure we do not update the UI if another task has started.
       newCts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
       
       // Update UI
    }
    catch(OperationCancelledException){
        // Ignore, or handle somehow
    }

}

This require "longerrunningtask" to be able to cancel cleanly, and never leave something in an inconsistent state. Ideally it should be "pure", i.e. without any side effects.
Since everything after the await is also running on the UI thread you will have a guaranteed ordering. So if someone cancels at the same time a previous task completes, either the task updates the UI, and the cancellation does nothing, or the task is cancelled and the UI is not updated.
Calling ThrowIfCancellationIsRequested after the task has completed might be appropriate when reading data. But if you are writing or updating something you might want to show a confirmation if it actually completed, regardless if some other task has been started concurrently. You might also want to have some restrictions about what operations can be started before the previous completes.

The assumption about running on the UI Thread, only eliminates the racing condition in the first 3 lines, right?

@Fildor Sure, there will be a race if the previous invocation resumes before the next starts. But that is kind of the point? Or do you see any harmful race condition?

No, no. I just wanted my understanding of this reassured. All good.

Instead of if (!newCts.IsCancellationRequested) { I would prefer newCts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();, so that there is only one cancellation code path instead of two.

@TheodorZoulias nice suggestion, updated.

You would need to cancel the cancellationTokenSource and create a new before starting the longerrunningtask, also if called from multiple endpoints you would need a lock.
private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new();
private readonly object lockObject = new();

void DoSomething()
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    Task.Run(async() => {await longerrunningtask(cancellationTokenSource.Token)}, ...)
       .ContinueWith((t) => { .... });
}

Depending on what longerrunningtask does perhaps a better option would be to ignore incoming calls to DoSomething if the task is running instead of restarting it.
